# Angular Promise don't work : ERROR TypeError: DataSource is undefined

Tags: angular, async-await, promise, undefined, angular-promise

i have issue by waiting dataSource is populated:

HTML

```
<app-single-y-axis [xAxysDataSource]="dataSource['labels']"
                   [yAxysDataSource]="dataSource['series']">
</app-single-y-axis>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getData();
}

getData = async () => {
  this.dataSource = await this.dataService.getDataAnalysis();
}
```

i try also (but got the same result):

```
 getData = async () => {
     this.dataService.getDataAnalysis()
      .then (res => {
          this.dataSource = res;
      })
    })
 }
```

DATASERVICE

```
getDataAnalysis = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     do something...
     this.anotherService.deviceDataAnalysis()
       .then(analysisRes => { i'll do what i have to do and works}
     }
  })
}
```

ANOTHERSERVICE

```
deviceDataAnalysisPromise() {
return this.http.post(BACKEND_URL + "url")
  .pipe(map((res: any) => {
    return res;
  })).toPromise();
```

The problem is that when i run it, in console log i have

```
ERROR TypeError: ctx_r31.dataSource is undefined
```

refered to HTML, for 3 / 7 time, it depends, until dataSource is populated... i don't understand how to tell him better to wait the response of all before start to go in panic...

Obviusly when dataSource is populated all works good

can someone help me please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved in this way

HTML

```
<span *ngIf="DataSourceDefined">
```

and in my component i put DataSourceDefined = true when it receive the dataSource...

Answer (score 1):

Your promise returned by `getDataAnalysis` never get resolved.
Instead of creating a `new Promise()` you could simply return the one you already have:

```js
getDataAnalysis = async () => {
  return this.anotherService.deviceDataAnalysis()
       .then(analysisRes => { return "i'll do what i have to do and works"});
}
```

Comment: Thank you but... it doesn't work :(... it alway don't wait for it and print ERROR TypeError: ctx_r32.dataSource is undefined